# getting id from a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string whose contents will vary but structure will always be the same

```
Tree_Group&lang=&discussionID=1012&t=viewDiscussion
```

How can I extract discussionID from it? No matter how long or short it may be

E.g.  6745

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match('/discussionID=([^&]+)/', $your_string, $matches);`

`$matches[1]` should contain your ID.

Comment: change `[^&]+` to `[^&]*` to match empty values

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it with [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
// strip out "Tree_Group&"
$str = str_replace("Tree_Group&", "", "Tree_Group&lang=&discussionID=1012&t=viewDiscussion");

// parse string as if it we a url query string (putting results into output)
parse_str($str, $output);

// get discussionID
$discussionID = $output["discussionID"];
```